# validate login & redirect to success page using jquery validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am new to advance level of jQuery scripting and here I am using jquery validation for my login page.

If my login page was success it has to redirect to success page the code was working fine with the below code when I click submit button .

```
<form id="form1" name="login" method="post" action="mainpage.html">

</form>
```

Here is my code

```
$(function (){
     $("#form1").validate({
    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        }
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        username: "Please enter a valid email address",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
          submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                         $('#username').focus();
                         $('#submit').click(function () {
                             event.preventDefault(); // prevent PageReLoad                                
                             var ValEmail = $('#username').val() === 'admin@admin.com'; // Email Value
                             alert("Email" + ValEmail);
                             var ValPassword = $('#password').val() === 'admin1234'; // Password Value
                             if (ValEmail === true && ValPassword === true) { // if ValEmail & Val ValPass are as above
                                 alert('valid!'); // alert valid!
                                 window.location.href = "http://java67.blogspot.com";
                                 // go to home.html
                             }
                             else {
                                 alert('not valid!'); // alert not valid!
                             }
                         });
                     }
    }
});

});
```

But I need to do validation example if emailid = admin@admin.com & passsword = admin1234 when I click the submit it needs to check whether my emailid was John@xyz.com and passsword was password if both was successful it has to redirect, else it has to show error message in the label.

Now I am getting the error as HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Here is the Fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/ny9bt1ak/4/)

Thanks in advance

Regards
M

Comment: You should not be using a `click` handler with this plugin.  There are methods built into the plugin, such as `submitHandler`, you should be using instead.  You should also show the code in your OP in addition to the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken for the following reasons...

1)  You've incorrectly placed the `success` option inside of the `messages` option.  The `success` option is a *sibling* of `messages`, not a child.

```
messages: {
    username: "Please enter a valid email address",
    password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
    },
    success: function (data) {  // <- does not belong inside of 'messages' option
        ....
    }
}
```

2)  [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#success), the `success` options is for: *"If specified, the error label is displayed to show a valid element."*  In other words, only use `success` if you want the error label to also be shown when there is no error; like for a green checkmark effect.

3)  Your `success` function has nothing to do with the intended purpose of the `success` option.  What's the point of using a validation plugin if you're going to manually write a validation function?  See my comments.

```
success: function (data) {
    if (username == 'john@xyz.com' && password == password) { // this is what the plugin does automatically when it evaluates the rules
        window.location = "mainpage.html"; // this is already the 'action' part of your '<form>'
    }
    else {
        $('#username').focus();  // Again, the plugin already does this.
    }
}
```

Simply let the plugin operate as designed...

- When validation fails, you'll get a message and the field will come into focus.
- When validation passes, the form will submit and redirect to the `mainpage.html` URL as specified by the `action="mainpage.html"` attribute of your `<form>`.

Your jsFiddle updated...

http://jsfiddle.net/sparky672/ny9bt1ak/3/