# After submit the login page Getting error as HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Working on login page using jquery validate plugin. After enter the correct username and password validation was working fine I created with the help of jquery validate. But the page was nto redirect to success page.

I am getting an Error as **HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**

Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
             $("#form1").validate({
                 debug: false,
                 errorClass: "error error_red",
                 rules: {
                     username: {
                         required: true,
                         email: true
                     },
                     password: {
                         required: true,
                         minlength: 5
                     }
                 },
                 messages: {
                     username: "Please enter a valid email address",
                     password: {
                         required: "Please provide a password",
                         minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                     },

                     success: function (data) { // for demo
                         $('#username').focus();
                     }
                 }
             });
             $('#submit').click(function () {
                 alert("check click");
                 var ValEmail = $('#username').val() == 'admin@admin.com'; // Email Value
                 alert("Email" + ValEmail);
                 var ValPassword = $('#password').val() === 'admin'; // Password Value
                 if (ValEmail === true && ValPassword === true) { // if ValEmail & Val ValPass are as above
                     alert('valid!'); // alert valid!
                     var site_url = 'http://localhost:55170/home_page.html';
                     alert("site_url" + site_url);
                     jQuery("#submit").click(function (event) {
                         alert("submit click" + jQuery("#submit").click);
                         window.location.href = site_url + "event-form";
                     });
                     // go to home.html
                 }
                 else {
                     alert('not valid!'); // alert not valid!
                 }
             });
         });
```

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bjkup35a/)

Thanks in advance
M

Comment: be particular, which creates problem?

Comment: Why do you have a whole other validation routine inside of a `click` handler?  The `click` handler and the function inside is not needed!  This code also contains the same problem (`success` option inside of `messages` option) that we already solved in your previous question.  Remove the entire `click` handler and use that other solution.

Comment: In other words, putting `success` inside of `messages` is breaking the validation plugin, so you're writing a whole new validation routine inside of a `click` handler to get around the problem you created.

Comment: `Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed` has absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript. See:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942051

Comment: Hi @Sparky thank you so much for the reply i want now how to solve the issue so I put the entire code again now I have changed

Comment: **Putting the `success` option inside of the `messages` option is completely wrong**... it's a mistake that will break the jQuery Validate plugin.  This was already explained in your previous question.  Instead of moving forward and solving a new problem, you've moved backwards to the previously broken code.  So you appear to have two completely separate issues, JavaScript that you keep breaking yourself and something else wrong with your server.

Comment: sorry @Sparky for the inconvenience caused can you please tell me how to solve this error

Comment: No, I do not know anything about Microsoft servers.  But I recommend that you stick with the very straightforward and standard code I provided in my previous answer to you.  The code I provided simply uses the very standard `<form>` `action` URL for the submit redirect; this is how forms have always worked since the beginning of HTML.  Messing up your JavaScript is not going to solve server errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered your code. try this...
Problems

- You are using '===' for comparing password.
- You are using same '===' in the if condition loop

> ```
> $('#submit').click(function () {
>                      alert("check click");
>                      var ValEmail = $('#username').val() == 'admin@admin.com'; // Email Value
>                      alert("Email" + ValEmail);
>                      var ValPassword = $('#password').val() == 'admin'; // Password Value
>                      if (ValEmail == true && ValPassword == true) { // if ValEmail & Val ValPass are as above
>                          alert('valid!'); // alert valid!
>                          var site_url = 'home_page.html';
>                          alert("site_url" + site_url);
>                          jQuery("#submit").click(function (event) {
>                              alert("submit click" + jQuery("#submit").click);
>                              window.location.href = site_url + "event-form";
>                          });
>                          // go to home.html
>                      }
>                      else {
>                          alert('not valid!'); // alert not valid!
>                      }
>                  });
> ```

Comment: He is using jQuery Validate plugin, so no need for any of this code, or even a `click` handler.

Comment: brother i altered his jsfiddle too, its working perfectly.Actually this code is taken from his JSFiddle only.

Comment: Did you read my comment?  I said... "there is ***no need*** for any of this code or a `click` handler" when using the jQuery Validate plugin.  It's redundant and superfluous.

Comment: can you please elaborate, i cant get you..

Comment: In other words, the OP putting the `success` option inside of the `messages` option is breaking the validation plugin; so then he's writing a whole new validation routine inside of a `click` handler to get around the plugin he broke.  All he needs to do is remove the entire `click` handler function and use the plugin as designed.

Comment: I already pointed out his mistake here, but he keeps doing it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353800/validate-login-redirect-to-success-page-using-jquery-validate-plugin

Comment: hi all 

actually my problem was I am getting an as HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

I have tried using Sparky code but still I am getting an Error

Comment: @MahadevanSivasubramanian, with my code, the form simply redirects to the URL as specified in `action` attribute of your `<form>`... that's standard HTML form behavior since the beginning of time.  If that URL is giving you a `405.0 Method not Allowed` error, then you have a Microsoft server issue that has nothing to do with JavaScript or the jQuery Validate plugin.  See:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942051